# Блок нестандартной формы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как можно сделать `div` такой формы,в какую сторону копать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Копайте в сторону paint, photoshop, gimp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вебу такие блоки чужды и использовать их не стоит.
Но если очень надо...
Можно использовать `canvas`, `svg`, молитвы Богам, но можно и на `HTML+CSS` с помощью [функций трансформации](http://html5book.ru/css3-transform/):

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#f{
  width: 50px;
}
#s{
  width: 70px;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}
#t{
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div id='f'></div><div id='s'></div><div id='t'></div>
```